# 500 code when model instance with foreign key is created

Tags: python, django

I'm not sure why I am getting a ValueError when I try to create a `ContactRequest` model object.

output:

```
(Pdb) unt
--Return--
> /Users/bli1/Development/Django/Boothie/home/views.py(80)load_home_content()->None
-> contact_request = ContactRequest(message=message, user=new_user.id)
(Pdb) l
 75                     phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
 76                     new_user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, phone_number=phone_number, email=email)
 77                     pdb.set_trace()
 78                     new_user.save()
 79                     message = form.cleaned_data['message']
 80  ->                 contact_request = ContactRequest(message=message, user=new_user.id)
 81                     if contact_request:
 82                         print "bad"
 83                     contact_request.save()
 84                     # pdb.set_trace()
 85                 return
(Pdb) unt
ValueError: ValueErr...tance.',)
> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py(111)get_response()
-> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
(Pdb) l
106                             break
107     
108                 if response is None:
109                     wrapped_callback = self.make_view_atomic(callback)
110                     try:
111  ->                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
112                     except Exception as e:
113                         # If the view raised an exception, run it through exception
114                         # middleware, and if the exception middleware returns a
115                         # response, use that. Otherwise, reraise the exception.
116                         for middleware_method in self._exception_middleware:
(Pdb)
```

view.py

```
def load_home_content(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print request.POST
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        print "form"
        print(form)
        # pdb.set_trace()
        if form.is_valid():
            # after is_valid(), the validated form data willbe in the form.cleaned_data dictionary.
            # Data will have been nicely converted into Python types
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
                print("email exists")
                return render(request, 'home/home.html')
            else:
                print("email/user does not exist")
                first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
                last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
                phone_number = form.cleaned_data['phone_number']
                new_user = User(first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name, phone_number=phone_number, email=email)
                pdb.set_trace()
                new_user.save()
                message = form.cleaned_data['message']
                contact_request = ContactRequest(message=message, user=new_user.id)
                if contact_request:
                    print "bad"
                contact_request.save()
                # pdb.set_trace()
            return render(request, 'home/home.html')
        else:
            print "form invalid"
    return render(request, 'home/home.html', {'form': ContactForm})
```

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name

    class Meta:
        db_table = "home_users"


class ContactRequest(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    datetime_created = models.DateTimeField("Datetime created", auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "home_contactrequests"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should pass the `User` instance to the `ContactRequest` constructor:

```
contact_request = ContactRequest(message=message, user=new_user)
```

Comment: And what is the message of this `TypeError`?

Comment: I'm not sure. I just found out about `pdb` today so all I can see right now is http://dpaste.com/39A12Q5

Comment: Then don't use `pdb` :-)  Set `DEBUG=True` in the `settings.py` and use the nice interface of the standard django error page.  It contains a lot of details about occured error.

Comment: DEBUG is set to True in my settings but if I comment out the `pdb` parts, `runserver` gives me this. http://dpaste.com/0FVN5DG  I'm not sure what to do to fix this issue because I dont know how to get more information out of the output =/

Comment: Error is displayed in the browser window, not in the `runserver` console.

Comment: Here ya go: http://postimg.org/image/umxorxgv5/eb52c98e/
http://dpaste.com/2X41QGE    Did not realize I can see errors here!!

Comment: Try to send this form data as regular html form without any ajax calls. I suppose that error is not in the code you published here.